# Tell IPython Parallel to use Pickle again after Dill has been activated

Tags: ipython, pickle, ipython-parallel, dill

I'm developing a distributed application using IPython parallel. There are several tasks which are carried out one after another on the IPython cluster engines.
One of these tasks inevitably makes use of closures. Hence, I have to tell IPython to use Dill instead of Pickle by calling `dv.use_dill()`. Though this should be temporarily.

Is there any way to activate Pickle again once Dill is enabled? I couldn't find any function (something of the form `dv.use_pickle()`) which would make such an option explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the `dill` author.  I don't know if `IPython` does anything unusual, but you can revert to `pickle` if you like through `dill` directly with `dill.extend(False)`… although this is a relatively new feature (not yet in a stable release).

If `IPython` doesn't have a `dv.use_pickle()` (it doesn't at the moment), it should… and could just use the above to do it.

Comment: I'm confused I get a message saying `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'extend'` I typed `dill.extend(False)`

Comment: It's a more recent feature of `dill` (as noted, it's not in a stable release). Do you have an older version?  A new release is imminent (as of this writing), but until then, if you want `dill.extend`, then you'd need to grab the bleeding edge version off github.

Comment: I had the same problem.  However, it's in the latest release of `dill`.

Comment: It's in the stable releases.